# Failed to find environment variable ANDROID_HOME while working with cordova ubuntu

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, ubuntu-16.04

I am new in Hybrid app development.I have been assigned a task to develop Android & IOS app using Cordova apache.

As I work on Lamp environment, so I started installing the software for the same.
Software I have installed are 
Cordova
npm
Android studio 
apache ant
PhoneGap

But even after installing and following the all the instructions given on the internet.I am not able to prepare my build for the testing purpose.

Below is the error I am facing/getting when running the command sudo cordova requirements

> Requirements check results for android: Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: not installed  Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment
>   variable. Try setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android'
>   command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to
>   valid SDK directory. Android target: not installed  Android SDK not
>   found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default
>   location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Gradle: not
>   installed  Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Could not
>   find Android SDK directory. Might need to install Android SDK or set
>   up 'ANDROID_HOME' env variable. Error: Some of requirements check
>   failed

Note:I have already set the environment variable in .bashrc file ,but still facing the issue .

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

in `/home/user/.bashrc` you must to set the ANDROID_HOME and PATH like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk/
```

and you PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/:$PATH
```